# Getting an Async action creator test to pass Redux

Tags: javascript, testing, redux, jestjs

I have an async actionCreator which sends off an API call - on success it gives the reponse on failure - it fails.  I am writing tests for the call but I can't get the test to send back the correct response.

Here is the function I am testing - Each dispatch dispatches an action.

```
const getStudyData = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(fetchStudiesBegin());
    const res = await  DataService.fetchAllStudyData();
    dispatch(fetchStudiesSuccess(res))
  }
  catch (err) {
    dispatch(fetchStudiesError(err))
  }
  }
} 


const fetchStudiesBegin = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_STUDIES_BEGIN
});

const fetchStudiesSuccess = studies => ({
  type: types.FETCH_STUDIES_SUCCESS,
  payload: { studies }
});

const fetchStudiesError = error => ({
  type: types.FETCH_STUDIES_ERROR,
  payload: { error }
});
```

This is the test that I have written - It is however giving me the ERROR response instead of the SUCCESS response

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

  describe('Test thunk action creator for the API call for studies ', () => {
    it('expected actions should be dispatched on successful request', () => {
      const store = mockStore({});
      const expectedActions = [
        types.FETCH_STUDIES_BEGIN,
        types.FETCH_STUDIES_SUCCESS
      ];

      // Mock the fetch() global to always return the same value for GET
      // requests to all URLs.
      fetchMock.get('*', { response: 200 });

      return store.dispatch(dashboardOperations.getStudyData())
        .then(() => {
          const actualActions = store.getActions().map(action => action.type);
          expect(actualActions).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });

      fetchMock.restore();
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: What exception is thrown? You don't log that anywhere, you just catch it and then pass it to `fetchStudiesError`. Check `payload.error`. Probably something thrown from inside `DataService.fetchAllStudyData`.

Comment: No error in the code - Only in the test - (maybe something to do with fetchmock? This is first time I have used it @SergiuParaschiv

Comment: Maybe `DataService.fetchAllStudyData` expects a certain response body structure? Only way to tell is to actually log that exception and see what the message is.

Comment: I get this message " Request failed with status code 401"  The dataService in the code needs headers added to it for the request to work - Do i need to add headers to fetchMock?